# htaccess URL Rewrite not working after 301 redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following url rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^info/([^/\.]+)/?$ info.php?page=info&subpage=$1 [L]
```

Originally the parameters were the page id's i.e. 0-10.
I have now changed this so the URLs have more meaningful slug names to reflect the content.

I have now set up the 301 redirects, for example:

```
Redirect 301 /info/0 http://www.example.com/info/intro
```

But the problem is, the redirect doesn't go to the url rewrite (http://www.example.com/info/intro). Instead it shows the full url (http://www.example.com/info.php?page=info&subpage=0)

How can it get it to keep the rewrite?
Many thanks

Comment: 1) Order of rules matters -- please show your full htaccess (at least all rules part). At least place your Redirect rule BEFORE rewrite rule. 2) Try converting Redirect to ReweriteRule form (which will still do the same job in the end) and place it BEFORE existing rewrite rule.

Comment: Thanks LazyOne. The redirect is already before the rewrite rule.  I'm not sure how to convert it to a RewriteRule - I'm new to all this :( I'll post my htaccess code... just need to trim it down a bit.

Comment: As simple as this: `RewriteRule ^info/0$ http://www.example.com/info/intro [R=301,L]`

Comment: Placing the following just before the url rewrite worked for me:   'RewriteRule ^intro/1$ http://www.example.com/info/intro [R=301,L]'
 I'll post this as an answer as soon as I can.  Apparently I have to wait 8 hours before I can do this! Thanks for your help LazyOne :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted by LazyOne, the solution was to use RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^info/0$ http://www.example.com/info/intro [R=301,L]
```